# Unable to execute a search for a specific column in a csv file using Ruby

Tags: ruby, csv

How to select a variable in a specific column in excel and printf the entire row using Ruby

I am able to execute a search for a certain word in a csv file. I am also able to print out the entire row. The issue is that I am unable to execute a search for a specific column in a csv file and print out the entire row.

I would need help regarding - selecting a priority level (which is on 4th column in excel) and puts the entire row using ruby

```
Equipment,Station,Status,Priority
floor,13,low,3
windows,2,medium,2
doors,14,high,1
lights,5,medium,2
lift,2,high,1


require "csv" 

alarms = CSV.read('alarms.csv')
highest = alarms.select { |level| level[0] =~ /high/}
puts highest.inspect
```

This code works if I were to look for /high/ 
but if I wanted to look for a Priority level of 2,

```
highest = alarms.select { |level| level[0] =~ /2/}
```

It will read the station column too.

How should I limit my code to read only from the priority column? Thanks! and
could some explain what this does? => |level| level[0]

~ ~ ~ Update ~ ~ ~

Here is my code and file path

[image]

[image]

this is how I execute my program.

[image]

Sorry if something is obviously wrong, but I couldnt get the results.

Would greatly appreciate if you could point it out thanks!

Comment: I've updated my answer. Hope that works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd make a method for it:

```
require 'csv'

def find_status_with_priority(status, priority)
  alarms = CSV.read 'alarms.csv'
  result = alarms.select do |level|
    level[2].downcase == status.downcase && level[3].to_i == priority.to_i
  end
  result
end

p find_status_with_priority('high', 1)
p find_status_with_priority('MEDIUM', '2')
```

this will give you all the alarms with the defined status and priority:

```
[["doors", "14", "high", "1"], ["lift", "2", "high", "1"]]
[["windows", "2", "medium", "2"], ["lights", "5", "medium", "2"]]
```

**Explanation**:

`select` is a Ruby method for the Array class, to which you are passing a block (the stuff in the curly braces).

`|level|` is a local variable you instantiate for the lifespan of that block. It means select all of `level` where `level` has this behavior.

`level[0]` is the first column of the array. `level[1]` is the second column and so on.

`.to_i` converts the string '1', '2' or '3' into integer values `1`, `2` or `3`. You then check for equality (i.e. `==`) with the priority you are looking for, in your case, `2`.

**Update**

To run the script from a console, run:

```
ruby alarms.rb
```

when you are in the same directory as the ruby file you are trying to execute.

Comment: I've made the changes as you suggested and the results was this [ ]. It happened to me all the time. I couldnt figure out why I always have an empty [ ] whenever I mess with the level[3] array

Comment: Post the exact steps you are running. Also, ensure the file `alarms.csv` is exactly the one you posted above. If it's not then you will get an empty array.

Comment: Could I get an upvote for my other answer?  I apparently need rep to post pictures

Comment: That's not really how StackOverflow works. Generally when people help you, you mark the helpful question with a check-mark.

Comment: Hi, I've managed to upload the images, please take a look if you have time, Thank you!!

Comment: Yup, my file path is alright as it works if I changed level[3] => level[0] It works well to search any keyword in my excel. So I'm wondering if there is a flaw in the way it searches the column? Also, is it right to save it as CSV (Comma delimited) (*.csv) ?

Comment: `It works well to search any keyword in my excel.`
I don't think I understand the problem you are facing. If it works for any keyword what is the issue you are encountering?

Comment: If I used this code  `highest = alarms.select { |level| level[0] =~ /high/}` I got row 4 and 6 as a successful result. But when I changed it to `high = alarms.select { |level| level[3].to_i == 2 }` it returns empty. 

The main issue I'm facing is: When I want to search using the suggestion you gave me, it returns nil.

Comment: Your question asks `How should I limit my code to read only from the priority column?`. Do you want it to search the priority column and the status columns combined?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the confusion. If you would, that would greatly help!

Comment: I've tried your code only to get blank arrays. I suppose there is a minor issue somewhere..

Comment: Hi Dani, may I know how would you add the col_sep option to this? I suspect that my csv isnt seperated by ',' but ';'

Comment: Replace the line `alarms = CSV.read 'alarms.csv'` with `alarms = CSV.read 'alarms.csv', {col_sep: ';'}`

Comment: It works now!! Thanks Dani, I really appreciate your help :)